# How to submit <form> from loaded page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with the form and I insert html into div. I try to insert button, but after inserting it with help of jquery - submit event of button not works.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     console.log("ready!");
     $("#radio").click(function(){
      console.log("radio clicked!");
      
      $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url: "content.html",
       success:function(data){
        $("#contentDiv").html(data);  
       },
       error:function(thrownError){
        console.log("error",arguments);
        console.log(thrownError);
       }
      });
     });
 });
</script>
<body>

<form action="page2.html">
<input id="radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</input>
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
`###content.html###`
<input type="submit" name="ok">OK</input>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: why are you inserting the button like that? seems very inefficient - why not either hide it if it doesn't exist or just create it rather than doing an ajax call to load it in.  Also inputs don't have a closing tag like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you element is created dynamically you need to use `on` document and target the button (`#buttonId" or .buttonclass`).

```
$(document).on("click", "#buttonId", function(){
/// your code comes here....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<form method="POST" id="login_form">
//form goes here
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit" />
</form> 


$(function() { //shorthand document.ready function
    $('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
        var data = $("#login_form :input").serializeArray();
        console.log(data); //use the console for debugging, F12 in Chrome, not alerts
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two events to handle depend on your preference:-

1. handle the form submit it self

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("ready!");
   $("#radio").click(function(){
       console.log("radio clicked!");

       $.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url: "content.html",
           success:function(data){
               $("#contentDiv").html(data);        
           },
           error:function(thrownError){
               console.log("error",arguments);
               console.log(thrownError);
           }
       });
   });
    // -----------------------------------------------------
   //add this if you want to handle form submit
   $( "#formId" ).submit(function( event ) {
   alert( "Handler for .submit() form called." );
   //event.preventDefault();
   });
    // -----------------------------------------------------
   });
   ```

give the form any id

```
   <form action="page2.html" onsubmit='alert("submit");' id="formId">
```

2. or handle the click event of the input type submit by updating the content.html

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="ok">OK</input>
   // -----------------------------------------------------
   <script>
     $( "input[name=ok]" ).click(function() {
     //put here you submit logic

   });
   </script>
   // -----------------------------------------------------
   ```